# Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration

Tags: flutter, gradle

Start getting this error after upgrading from gradle 3.6.4 to 4.0.1. What does this mean? How to resolve this?

```
> Task :app:lintVitalProductionRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalProductionRelease'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform libs.jar to match attributes {artifactType=processed-jar, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: /Users/yuchen/Documents/my_app/build/app/intermediates/flutter/debug/libs.jar.
         > Transform's input file does not exist: /Users/yuchen/Documents/my_app/build/app/intermediates/flutter/debug/libs.jar. (See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158753935)
```

Comment: I've the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: No, unfortunately. I had to revert back to 3.6.4.

Comment: I did the same. Won't be updating anything any time soon. That I'm sure.

Comment: I think without a [repro] this question can not get an objective answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried updating a project from gradle `3.5.0` to `4.0.1`, and it worked fine for me. There was just an error initially that prompted me to update the `distributionUrl` inside **android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties** to `gradle-6.1.1-all.zip`.

Have you tried running `flutter clean` and see if it solves the issue? Gradle version `4.2.2` is already available at the time of this writing, you might to try upgrading to that version instead if that works for you.

If you're still having issues, you can follow the workaround posted in this [GitHub issue thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/58247#issuecomment-636500680).